# How do I increase my sdb4 partition to include allocated space?

Tags: filesystem, gparted, disk-usage, development, unallocated

The unallocated space is shown here having 22GB and the size I want to increase is that of /dev/sdb4

[image]
Please do help :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Do not make your NTFS too small. Windows NTFS likes 30% free to run well. At 10%, your defrag may take forever as no working room to move parts of files around. Only use Windows tools to shrink NTFS partitions & reboot immediately, so it can run chkdsk. Best to houseclean or get larger drive or have your data on another drive. You have to use Ubuntu live installer which has gparted or gparted ISO. And move partition left & expand right. Little lock icons mean you are using gparted from inside your install, so you cannot unmount it and it has to be unmounted to edit it.